# CSS/HTML - forcing style to child from parent

Tags: css, html, parent, inheritance

I have a content div with `font-family:Tahoma`. When user click on a post clink an ajax code will fetch content of that post and put in my specific div.

On a normal situation (before clicking any link) the content shows in Tahoma font, The problem appears when the ajax is called and the new content is shown in **different font and size.**

How can I make the new printed content show in my desired font-family (Tahoma)? Meaning inherit the font from the parent.

**HERE IS MY HTML CODE** : http://jsfiddle.net/KZAVd/

This is what happens after clicking a post (checked using Firebug): http://jsfiddle.net/KZAVd/3/

Comment: can we get a before and after of the html?

Comment: You could add a class to it:

myclass {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
}

Comment: The content is being styled by "inline" styling. NOTHING you can do with css will change these, they will need to be fixed with javascript after you bring them in. Can you please post the AJAX you are using to import the content?

Comment: Thanks for looking back at my unsolved problems. here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/e6pKR/

Comment: Perfect, and now that you're on the jQuery boat, we can refactor this code to be much much more succinct ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to handle all the mundane tasks of AJAX yourself, let jquery do it.

```
function ajaxFunctionFinal(id, title, content)
{
    var queryString = "?post_id=" + id + "&ts=" + new Date().getTime();

    $.ajax({
        url: "fetch.php" + queryString,
        complete: function(data){
            $("#post_more").html( data.responseText )
                .find('*').removeAttr("style");
            $("#post_content").html( content );
            $("#post_title").html( title );
            InlineMp3();
        }
    });
}
```

The line of particular interest to you is `.find('*').removeAttr("style");` which will grab all descendants of the newly inserted content and toss their style attributes, thus crushing the in-line styles that came with them and allowing your css full control.

ps: I obviously can't test this, so feel free to comment with any problems, or post a full url to fetch.php so that I can test it with you (if that doesn't have private information)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is much better now

Answer (score 3):

A. make sure your ajax content is going into the same place as what was ok before.

and / or

B. Set `div.content, div.content *{font-family:Tahoma}`

Comment: Then it's time to post your HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KZAVd/2/ I cant see any problem. Body styles are following correctly.

Comment: I investigated the content div using FireBug after clicking a post. It seems the new generated code on page will be like this : http://jsfiddle.net/KZAVd/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can give the content div the following class:

```
.content * {
  font-family:Tahoma !important;
}
```

Like this:

```
<div class="content">
  ...ajax content...
</div>
```

This will force any child element to always have the Tahoma font.

Comment: I ran a test derived from your fiddle and it's working, even when you force a font-family in the child elements: http://jsfiddle.net/D3m8U/

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's explicitly set different, an element will inherit the font-family from it's parent element. Try using Firebug or a similar tool, and you'll be able to see exactly where the style is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

depending what your loading when you click the post link, try styling the post itself, not trying to style it after loading.

Comment: Yeah I know I can do that but that will be a pain-in-the-ass for changing every post font from wordpress side

Answer (score 0):

If you want the full page, try using a body tag:
     body{
     font-family:Tahoma;
     }
I will try to find another way

Answer (score 0):

you will need to explicitly set the font-family for the child